# Address Boundary Error With Vector of Structs

Tags: c++

I am trying to set up a vector of structs, and add data to the structs by reading a data file. The code parses the data file correctly, as I am able to print out the values using `songList[y]` instead of `songData[x].song`. When I run it, I always get the error `SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Song{
    string song;
    string band;
    string minutes;
    string seconds;
    string album;
};

vector <Song> songData; // Vector the data will eventually end up

// MAIN FUNCTION

int main(){
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    vector <string> songList;
    // Open file
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("songs.txt");
    // Add data to vector
    string tempLine;
    while(getline(infile, tempLine)){
        songData.push_back(Song());
        istringstream ss(tempLine);
        string temp;
    while(getline(ss, temp, ';')){
        songList.push_back(temp);
        if(x == 0){
                songData[x].song = songList[y];
                cout << "Song:\t" << songData[x].song << endl;
            }else if(x == 1){
                songData[x].band = songList[y];
                cout << "Band:\t" << songData[x].band << endl;
            }else if(x == 2){
                songData[x].minutes = songList[y];
                cout << "Min:\t" << songData[x].minutes << endl;
            }else if(x == 3){
                songData[x].seconds = songList[y];
                cout << "Sec:\t" << songData[x].seconds << endl;
            }else if(x == 4){
                songData[x].album = songList[y];
                cout << "Album:\t" << songData[x].album << endl;
            }else{
                cout << "Error!" << endl; // Will never run
        }
        x++;
        y++;
        if(x == 5){
            x = 0;
        }
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the data file (songs.txt):

```
Song 1;Band 1;Min 1;Sec 1;Album 1
Song 2;Band 2;Min 2;Sec 2;Album 2
Song 3;Band 3;Min 3;Sec 3;Album 3
Song 4;Band 4;Min 4;Sec 4;Album 4
Song 5;Band 5;Min 5;Sec 5;Album 5
```

Comment: You appear to be using the same variable (`x`) as both the index into `songData`, and as the discriminator for which field of your songdata to fill. One of those should be `y` instead, I assume?

Comment: Probably shouldn't be incrementing both those at the same time, either. You might want to step through the code with a debugger, or [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As a point to consider when asking for help: can you demonstrate your problem with less code?  e.g. could you still get a crash if it were only `struct Song { string song; };` without the rest?  If so, you should post the shorter code and keep it focused!  Read up on what a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is.  You can use the [`[edit]`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54489000/edit) button to edit your questions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind Segmentation Fault is the way you are using variable `x`.

Consider this:

```
while(getline(infile, tempLine)) {
    songData.push_back(Song()); // songData.size() = 1 after reading first line
    istringstream ss(tempLine);
    string temp;
```

Now consider second iteration of the below loop (i.e. reading of `Band 1`): At this point, `x = 1` and `songList.size() = 1`.

```
    while(getline(ss, temp, ';')) {
        songList.push_back(temp); // songList.size() = 2, after reading "Band 1"
        if(x == 0) {
            songData[x].song = songList[y];
            cout << "Song:\t" << songData[x].song << endl; 
        } else if(x == 1) {
            songData[x].band = songList[y]; // Undefined behaviour which may lead to Seg. Fault because songData.size() = 1 and you are trying to access 2nd element of songData.
            cout << "Band:\t" << songData[x].band << endl;
        }
        ...
        x++;
        y++;
        if(x == 5) {
            x = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the corrected code. I have removed vector `songList` because I think it was not required. Also, I have changed the usage of variables `x` and `y`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Song{
    string song;
    string band;
    string minutes;
    string seconds;
    string album;
};

vector <Song> songData; // Vector the data will eventually end up

// MAIN FUNCTION

int main(){
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    // Open file
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("songs.txt");
    // Add data to vector
    string tempLine;
    while (getline(cin, tempLine)) {
        songData.push_back(Song());
        istringstream ss(tempLine);
        string temp;

        while(getline(ss, temp, ';')){
            if(y == 0) {
                songData[x].song = temp;
                cout << "Song:\t" << songData[x].song << endl;
            } else if (y == 1) {
                songData[x].band = temp;
                cout << "Band:\t" << songData[x].band << endl;
            } else if (y == 2) {
                songData[x].minutes = temp;
                cout << "Min:\t" << songData[x].minutes << endl;
            } else if (y == 3) {
                songData[x].seconds = temp;
                cout << "Sec:\t" << songData[x].seconds << endl;
            } else if(y == 4) {
                songData[x].album = temp;
                cout << "Album:\t" << songData[x].album << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "Error!" << endl; // Will never run
            }
            y++;
            if(y == 5) {
                y = 0;
            }
        }

        x++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DylanConklin Did this answer your question?